# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „sinkend“ und „gesunken“ als Adj？

Tags: adjective

In diesem Satz:

> „Das im letzten Quartal um 1%______BIP...“

Heisst es „sinkende „oder „gesunkene“?

Answer (score 2):

Das im letzten Quartal gesunkene Bip...

Das sinkende würde bedeuten, dass es immer noch sinkt, doch die Temporalangabe „im letzten Quartal“ verlangt die Vergangenheitsform.

Sinkend ist ein Partizip Präsens (wird gebildet mit -nd als suffix)

Gesunken ist ein Partizip Perfekt (ge und -en)